# UIview error "" for Class function

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have written "Utils" class which contain class functions like :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

open class Utils {
    class func getMyTestView(fromView : UIView) {
    }
}
```

Application showing

> Use of undeclared type UIView

compile error. How do I solve it?
I have tried clean build and also deleted derive data. Still getting same error for Xcode 9.

Comment: just remove `import Foundation` and restart Xcode or clean, build.

Comment: I don't think the issue if from your code, try to restart your Xcode.

Comment: Delete `DerivedData` folder and then restart Xcode.